# Tryign to use Regex for numerals

Tags: java, regex

I have a dataset with now equal lines of elements. I am attempting to use a Distributed Cache in `MapReduce`. The the data looks like:

```
3467 r009345, r234956, r453437
8462 r6364785, r3450344, r0489832, r99982523
10093, r542557, r0922352
```

Code looks like this:

```
for(Path p: genes2snps)
{
    if(p.getName().equals("genes2snps.txt"));
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(p.toString()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            //String[] tokens = line.split("\t");
            String[] tokens = line.split("\t", limit)
            String geneID = tokens[0];
            String state = tokens["\^0"];

        }
    }
}
```

I Would like to say, use array[0] as a key and array[NOT 0] as the value. How do I do this is Regex?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What is this `while()`?

Comment: What is `tokens["\^0"];` supposed to be?

Comment: So you want a regex that assigns something like this: `new String[] { "3467", "r009345, r234956, r453437"}` for the first line?

Comment: I think I understand it now, I think you should be using simple pattern matching to extract your two values, a pattern like `([0-9]+)\\t(.*)` would give you two matching groups with the values you need.

Comment: so for instance, I would like a reged that identifies from location [1-3], for the first like, [1-4] for the second line and [1-2] for the third....something like [1*]